# Conditional Probability and Regular Conditional Probabilities

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I have a question regarding defining conditional probabilities and the concept of regular conditional probabilities.  I have read other posts but I am still struggling with certain issues.

Imagine we have a measurable map $X$ from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ to a measure space $(\tilde{\Omega}, \mathcal{G})$.  Let $\mathcal{F}_0 \in \mathcal{F}$.  Let $A \in \mathcal{G}$.

I want to define $\mathbb{P}(X \in A| \mathcal{F}_0)$ as $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_A(X)|\mathcal{F}_0)$. $\:$(*)

1) Is this an acceptable/standard definition?

2) If not, is the reason for regular conditional probabilities to deal with issues that may arise from the above definition?

3) I know conditional expectation is unique only up to null sets.  Is a possible issue with the above definition that for another $A' \in \mathcal{G}$ it may be the case that $\mathbb{P}(X \in A| \mathcal{F}_0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X \in A'| \mathcal{F}_0)$ do not "align" in the way we would want them to for certain $\omega$.

4) If the spaces are sufficiently "nice" is (*) a reasonable definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of regular conditional probability we want $P(X \in A|\mathcal F_0)$ to be a measure in $A$ and a measurable fuction  for fixed $A$. In view of the fact that conditional probabilites are defined only up to null sets (those null sets varying with $A$) it is impossible to get regular conditional probabilities directly from the definition of conditional probabilities, even in nice spaces. Considerable amount of work is needed to show that regular conditional probabilities exist in  nice spaces  (like Polish spaces).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  When you say "directly from the definition of conditional probabilities," can you tell me what you mean specifically by the definition of conditional probability with respect to my example?  Is it the definition in (*)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Thank you.  I am still struggling a bit with regular conditional probability.  I will need to read more than we can do in a comment section.  But perhaps we can do one final question.  Is the hope with a regular conditional probability that we can find a single unifying function that does the "work" similar to all of the standard conditional probability functions (even if it is not it does not itself come from these standard conditional probability functions or align with them)?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.