# Prove this $\phi$ mixing inequality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, conditional-expectation, mixing

Am trying to understand Theorem 2.2 in [Serfling (1968)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-39/issue-4/Contributions-to-Central-Limit-Theory-for-Dependent-Variables/10.1214/aoms/1177698240.full):

**Proposition.** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal F$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$. Let $X$ be a real random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$, and assume that $\|X\|_p<\infty$, where $1<p<\infty$. Then

$$ \|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\|_p\leq 2\phi(\mathcal A,\mathcal F)^{1-\frac{1}{p}} \|X\|_p $$

where $\phi(\mathcal A,\mathcal F)=\sup_{A\in \mathcal A, F\in \mathcal F, P(F)>0} \bigg|P(A|F)-P(A)\bigg|$.

**Proof. (Davidson (1994))**

First assume that $X$ is simple with representation

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i 1_{A_i}$$

with $a_i\in\mathbb R$, $A_i\in\mathcal A$, $\cup_{i=1}^n A_i=\Omega$, $A_i$ pairwise disjoints. Let $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$. Then

$$\Big|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\Big|^p=\Big|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|^p$$$$\leq \Big[\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| \Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|\Big]^p$$

$$=\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| \Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|^{1/p} \Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|^{1/q}\Big]^p$$

$$\leq \Big[\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^p \Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big| \Big] \Big[\sum_{i=1}^n\Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|\Big]^{p/q}$$

$$\leq \Big[ E[|X|^p|\mathcal F]+E[|X|^p] \Big] \Big[\sum_{i=1}^n\Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|\Big]^{p/q}$$

$P$-almost surely, where the second inequality comes from Hölder's inequality.

Now Davidson writes: Let $A^+$ denote the union of all those $A_i$ for which $P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\geq 0$, and let $A^-=\Omega\setminus A^+$. Then

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|=\Big|P[A^+|\mathcal F]-P[A^+]\Big|+\Big|P[A^-|\mathcal F]-P[A^-]\Big|$$

Why is this last equality true?

The next step is to claim

$$|P[A^+|\mathcal F]-P[A]|\leq \phi(\mathcal A,\mathcal F)$$

$$|P[A^-|\mathcal F]-P[A]|\leq \phi(\mathcal A,\mathcal F)$$

$P$-almost surely using the inequality from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4271253/522332).

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

For completeness I will try to finish the proof here. From the answers we have $$\sum_{i=1}^n\Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|\leq 2\phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F) \quad\quad P\text{-almost surely}$$

Substituing back we get

$$\Big|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\Big|^p\leq \Big[ E[|X|^p|\mathcal F]+E[|X|^p] \Big] \Big[2\phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F)\Big]^{p/q} \quad\quad P\text{-almost surely} $$

Integrating both sides gives

$$E\Big[\Big|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\Big|^p\Big]\leq 2E[|X|^p] \Big[2\phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F)\Big]^{p/q} $$

Raising both sides to the power $1/p$ we obtain

$$ \|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\|_p\leq 2\phi(\mathcal A,\mathcal F)^{1-\frac{1}{p}} \|X\|_p $$

Now assume $X$ is an arbitrary $\mathcal A$ measurable real random variable with $\|X\|_p<\infty$. Then there exists a sequence  $(X_n)$  of simple $\mathcal A$ measurable random variables such that  $|X_n|\leq|X_{n+1}|\leq |X|$ for each $n$ and $X_n\to X$ pointwise.

From the DCT using the dominating functions $|X|$, $|X|^p$ we get

$$ E[X_n]\to E[X]$$
$$E[|X_n|^p]\to E[|X|^p]$$

From the DCT for conditional expectations using the dominating functions $|X|$, $|X|^p$ we also have

$$ E[X_n|\mathcal F]\to E[X| \mathcal F] \quad \quad P\text{-almost surely}$$

$$ E[|X_n|^p|\mathcal F]\to E[|X|^p| \mathcal F] \quad \quad P\text{-almost surely}$$

From the first part we have

$$\Big|E[X_n|\mathcal F]-E[X_n]\Big|^p\leq \Big[ E[|X_n|^p|\mathcal F]+E[|X_n|^p] \Big] \Big[2\phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F)\Big]^{p/q} \quad\quad P\text{-almost surely} $$

for each $n$. Since a countable union of null sets is null, we can combine all these statements and pass to the limit to obtain

$$\Big|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\Big|^p\leq \Big[ E[|X|^p|\mathcal F]+E[|X|^p] \Big] \Big[2\phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F)\Big]^{p/q} \quad\quad P\text{-almost surely} $$

Taking expectations on both sides and raising to the power $1/p$ as before we get

$$\|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\|_p\leq 2\phi(\mathcal A,\mathcal F)^{1-\frac{1}{p}} \|X\|_p$$

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Comment: @d.k.o. The inequality I referenced says that $|P(A|\mathcal F)-P(A)|\leq \phi(\mathcal A,\mathcal F)$ $P$-a.s. for a fixed $A$. But here $B$ varies with $\omega$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @d.k.o. I found another proof in the book Stochastic Limit Theory by Davidson. But am stuck at some point (see my edit). Do you see why the equality holds?

Comment: Haha. I am looking at the same proof right now. Davidson's argument is essentially the same.

Comment: @d.k.o. The problem is that $A^+$ still depends on $\omega$. I don't see how to fix this. Seems like a technicality...

Comment: BTW, there is a typo in (14.21).

Comment: @d.k.o. Am reading Theorem 14.2 about the other mixing inequality in Davidson STL. It seems to me that his claim at (14.12) is wrong, or at least does not follow from what he did. Am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming that $|X|\le M$ and $\mathsf{E}|X|<4M\alpha$, $\mathsf{E}|X|^p=\mathsf{E}|X||X|^{p-1}\le 4M^p\alpha$. That is,
$$
\|X\|_p\le M(4\alpha)^{1/p}.
$$

Comment: Oh right! Should have thought about that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Davidson's proof. Let $\kappa(\cdot,\cdot)$ denote the r.c.p. w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}$, and let
$$
\nu(A,\omega):=\kappa(A,\omega)-\mathsf{P}(A).
$$

Then for each $\omega\in \Omega$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}|\nu(A_i,\omega)|=\nu(A^+(\omega),\omega)-\nu(A^-(\omega),\omega),
$$
and
$$
|\nu(A^+(\omega),\omega)|\vee  |\nu(A^-(\omega),\omega)| \le \max_{A\in \mathcal{A}}|\nu(A,\omega)|,
$$
where $\mathcal{A}=\{\bigcup_{i\in \mathcal{I}} A_i:\mathcal{I}\subset \{1,\ldots, n\}\}$. Now you can bound the rhs by the $\phi$-mixing coefficient.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will accept your answer, but I still think we need to be more careful with the dependence of $A^+,A^-$ on $\omega$. I tried to spell out the details below using your idea. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @Alphie So you don't like that $A^+(\omega)$ appears inside $\nu$? BTW, my initial idea was similar to your answer.

Comment: The equality $\sum_{i=1}|\nu(A_i,\omega)|=\nu(A^+(\omega),\omega)-\nu(A^-(\omega),\omega)$ does not seem immediate to me, because additivity of conditional expectation holds a.s. for a fixed set. I think we need to pick $\omega$ such that additivity holds uniformly over all subsets $\mathcal{I}\subset \{1,\ldots, n\}$. This holds a.s. since there are only finitely many such subsets.

Comment: I did the same thing really, but I only considered $\omega$ outside a null set such that additivity holds uniformly over $\mathcal{I}\subset \{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Comment: I see your point. On the other hand, $\nu(\cdot,\omega)$ is a proper measure for each $\omega$. So, $\omega$-wise $\nu(B_1,\omega)+\nu(B_2,\omega)=\nu(B_1\cup B_2,\omega)$.

Comment: Am not sure I understand what is $\kappa$ here? Regular conditional distributions are defined for random variables but here there are none? Why don't you use the conditional probability instead?

Comment: I meant the Markov kernel on $\mathcal{A}\times \Omega$ as in the proof of Theorem 2.2 in Serfling's paper.

Comment: Ok but how is this markov kernel related to $P[A_i|\mathcal F]$?

Comment: It is a version of $\mathsf{P}(\cdot\mid \mathcal{F})$ that has nice properties.

Comment: How do you know that it exists? The target space here  is $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$, which is not necessarily nice. From Wiki we need the target space to be Polish to show existence of such a markov kernel. See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3203918/522332

Comment: Is this measure well defined? I mean we could have $A=X^{-1}(B_1)=X^{-1}(B_2)$ with $B_1\neq B_2$ no?

Comment: I'll rephrase that comment given a specific structure of $X$, which takes distinct values $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ corresponding to the sets $A_1,\ldots, A_n$.

Comment: Since r.c.p.s need not exist, we can define $\kappa$ as a probability measure on $\mathcal{P}(\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\})$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$ as follows. For each $I\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}$,
$$
\kappa\!\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i,\omega\right)=P_X\!\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}a_i,\omega\right),
$$
where $P_X$ is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: I guess you mean a probability measure on $\sigma(\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\})=\{\bigcup_{i\in \mathcal{I}} A_i:\mathcal{I}\subset \{1,\ldots, n\}\}$. OK this seems to work. We need the $a_i$ to be the distinct values of $X$  (standard representation) for the measure to be well defined. Finiteness of the generator is key. Seems like am doing the same thing "by hand". Do you think my approach is also valid?

Comment: Sure, your approach is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. One last thing: Am trying to finish to proof using DCT (see my post edit) but am having issues in the last step. Do you see how to obtain convergence on the LHS?

Comment: It looks like it would be easier to apply the (conditional) DCT to
$$
\Big|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\Big|^p\leq \Big[ E[|X|^p|\mathcal F]+E[|X|^p] \Big] \Big[2\phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F)\Big]^{p/q}.
$$
Then you can proceed as before.

Comment: Absolutely! I modified accordingly. Seems right now?

Comment: @Alphie Looks good to me.

Comment: Take you for your time. This inequality made we sweat!

Comment: Indeed, both sources were not accurate enough.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a version of $P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i|\mathcal F]$ for each $\mathcal I\subset {\{1,\dots,n}\}$. Put $$Z(\omega)=\max_{\mathcal I\subset {\{1,\dots,n}\}}\Bigg|P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i]\Bigg|$$

for each $\omega\in\Omega$. For a fixed subset $\mathcal I\subset {\{1,\dots,n}\}$, using the disjointness of the $A_i$, we have

$$ P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i|\mathcal F]=\sum_{i\in\mathcal I}P[A_i|\mathcal F]\quad\quad P\text{-almost surely.}$$

Since there are only finitely many subsets $\mathcal I\subset {\{1,\dots,n}\}$, taking a finite union of null sets gives a set $N$ with $P(N)=0$ such that

$$ P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)=\sum_{i\in\mathcal I}P[A_i|\mathcal F](\omega) \quad \quad (1)$$

for all $\mathcal I\subset {\{1,\dots,n}\}$ and all $\omega\in\Omega\setminus N$.

Now fix some $\omega\in\Omega\setminus N$.

Let $\mathcal I^+_\omega$ denote the set of all $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $P[A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[A_i]\geq 0$, and let $\mathcal I^-_\omega$ denote the set of all $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $P[A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[A_i]< 0$.

Then using $(1)$ we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[A_i]\Big|=\sum_{i\in \mathcal I^+_\omega}\Big[P[A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[A_i]\Big]-\sum_{i\in\mathcal I^-_\omega}\Big[P[A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[A_i]\Big]$$

$$=\Big[P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I^+_\omega}A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I^+_\omega}A_i]\Big]-\Big[P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I^-_\omega}A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I^-_\omega}A_i]\Big]$$

$$\leq\Big|P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I^+_\omega}A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I^+_\omega}A_i]\Big|+\Big|P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I^-_\omega}A_i|\mathcal F](\omega)-P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I^-_\omega}A_i]\Big|$$

$$\leq 2Z(\omega)$$

As this holds for all $\omega\in\Omega\setminus N$ we have shown that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|\leq 2Z \quad\quad P\text{-almost surely} \quad\quad (2)$$

Now, the inequality from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4271253/522332) implies that

$$\Bigg|P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i|\mathcal F]-P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i]\Bigg| \leq \phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F)\quad\quad P\text{-almost surely,} \quad \text{ for each }  \mathcal I\subset \{1,\dots,n\}$$

and since there are only finitely many subsets $\mathcal I\subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ we can take a finite union of null sets to obtain

$$\Bigg|P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i|\mathcal F]-P[\cup_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i]\Bigg| \leq \phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F)\quad\quad  \text{ for each }  \mathcal I\subset \{1,\dots,n\},\quad P\text{-almost surely}$$

which implies $Z\leq \phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F)$ $P$-almost surely. Combined with $(2)$ this gives

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\Big|P[A_i|\mathcal F]-P[A_i]\Big|\leq 2\phi (\mathcal A,\mathcal F) \quad\quad P\text{-almost surely} $$